# Integration of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2 + 2x} dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

The question is easy to phrase:

Show that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2 + 2x} dx
$$
converges and compute its value.

A first thing I did is simplifying it to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-y^2 + 1} dy $. Now it is also symmetric along zero so calculating it on $[0, \infty)$ is enough.

Then I started looking for an antiderivative in numerous ways, but without succes. For example if I try deriving $f(y)e^{-y^2 + 1}$ for a so far unspecified function $f$, I get
$$
d \left(f(y)e^{-y^2 + 1}\right)/dy = f'(y)e^{-y^2 +1} - 2y \cdot f(y) e^{-y^2 + 1}
$$
using the product rule, but I couldn't find a solution to the differential equation $f' -2yf = 1$...

A hint should be fine so I can figure out the rest myself. This question is part of an entrance exam for a PhD program of some years ago. I will be taking the exam this year, so it is not so much about this particular question, but more about the general methods to tackle such questions. So if the answer could be somehow phrased for general such questions that would be great.

Comment: Is $x$ a function of $y$?, wouldn't $\int e^{-x^2+2x}dy = e^{-x^2+2x}\int dy$? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Your simplification is not equivalent to the original integrand.

Comment: Fixed the typo, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\, dx$ is a Gaussian integral, which can be evaluated in a number of ways. One method of attack, usually taught in multivariate calculus classes, is to square the integral and convert to polar coordinates. It will be $\int_0^\infty \int_0^{2\pi} e^{-r^2} r\, d\theta\, dr$. After computing this, take the square root to get the result.

One complex variable approach is to consider the contour integral $\int_{\gamma} e^{-z^2}\, dz$, where $\gamma$ is the boundary of a sector of radius $R$, in the first quadrant, subtended by the angle $\pi/4$, with counterclockwise orientation.

Comment: Hi Kobe, could you state the other ways from the "number of ways"? I'll check them out via google. Thanks!

Comment: @Joachim, here are ten different ways to do it:
http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf .
And a cool short article about the Gaussian integral:
http://folk.ntnu.no/oistes/Diverse/gaussian-integral-puzzle.pdf

Comment: @Joachim Are you familiar with the $\Gamma$ function?

Comment: That is great @kobe, I will check it out.

Comment: @Joachim I mentioned a contour integral approach that is not covered in K. Conrad's notes. Instead of integrating over a rectangle, we integrate over the boundary of a sector subtended by $\pi/4$.

Answer (score 13):

You should be aware (see kobe's answer) that 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt\pi.$$

Now, 
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2+2x}\,dx& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2+2x-1}e\,dx\\
& =e\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-1)^2}\,dx\\
& =e\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt\quad\quad\quad t=x-1\\
& =e\sqrt\pi.
\end{align}$$

Comment: It can also be achieved via [Feynman integration](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-304-undergraduate-seminar-in-discrete-mathematics-spring-2006/projects/integratnfeynman.pdf).

Comment: @Miguelgondu why not show that method working in an additional answer?

Comment: I know it can be done, I'm not sure how though. I'm unable to find the parametrization. I shared the link because I thought it might be interesting for the OP.

Comment: @Miguelgondu Ah something new to me....I'll have to check it out.

Comment: I've found it to be very useful and nice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tim. The other addressed my question slightly more directly, so I accepted that one. Nevertheless your one was useful as well!

Comment: Your welcome. I overlooked the part about needing just a hint.  Had I seen that I would have given the same answer as kobe.

Comment: @Miguelgondu I added a CW answer with some possible insight to that method.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what to make of it, but here is some fun insight for 'Feynman integration' or integration under the differentiation sign.
$$
\begin{align}
f(a)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2 + ax} dx\\
f'(a)&=a\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2 + ax} dx\\
\implies f'(a)&=af(a)\\
\implies\frac{f'(a)}{f(a)}&=a\\
\implies \log f(a)&=\frac{a^2}{2}+c\\
\implies f(a) &= e^{a^2/2+c}\\
f(2)&=e\ e^{c+1}\\
\implies c&=\log\sqrt\pi-1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, that's a nice parametrization.

Comment: I think you have some sort of mistake, now that I think about it. In the second line, I think that, after partially deriving, one arrives to $f'(a) = \int_{\infty}^{\infty} xe^{-x^2+ax}$, because you're deriving with respect to $a$. Or am I wrong?